# What is the usage of NSResponder's indent:?

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsresponder

NSResponder has a method you override called - indent:, but unsure when it would normally be activated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's typically used in programming text editors to fix up the indentation of a piece of code, e.g. converting:

```
for (...) {
something
}
```

into:

```
for (...) {
    something
}
```

If you're not familiar with Cocoa Text's key binding system, see [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TextDefaultsBindings/TextDefaultsBindings.html) — it's pretty powerful and flexible.